# Does .htaccess file cache previous instructions?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, plesk

slightly weird issue here I cant get my head around.

So ive been playing around with my .htaccess file in an extremely amateurish way. I successfully added a simple 301 redirect from one URL to another. However I have since deleted this instruction and the redirection still occurs.

To comfound matters I added another rule into the file and this was not being executed. I tried deleting the file. This stopped the initial 301 redirect from occuring (even though the instruction was not in the file).

I readded the .htcaccess file and added my new rule, this now works but the original 301 redirection is still occuring.

this is really befuddling me, if anyone has any idea what is going on here help would be appreciated.

Im running plesk 12 if that makes any difference.

So now my .htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

however my url /pages/page still 301 redirects to /page (even though there is obviously not a rule in there anymore for this)

Comment: Are you clearing your browser cache before retesting?

Comment: Yeah even tried it on edge (which I (like I assume everyone else) don't use for anything)

Comment: It's weird right? I'm not just missing some very obvious reason for this?

Comment: To answer your original question, htaccess doesn't cache any instructions. I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but you can use 302 redirects until you have it figured out, that will take browser caching out of the equation (as long as you are not sending expires or cache-control headers).

Comment: I meant more like server side caching (if that's a thing) I've ruled out browser issues

Comment: No, .htaccess is executed on each request. You can confirm this by adding some junk like "blah" on separate line, it should throw a 500 error. If you have .htaccess files in other directories they could be interfering. You can also set a trace level in httpd.conf and check the apache error log to follow along with exactly what .htaccess is doing for each request.

Comment: Ah cool, how would I go about adding a trace? Do you want to add that as solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to debug issues like this is to enabled logging for mod rewrite, for example adding `LogLevel info rewrite:trace5` in httpd.conf and tailing the apache error log to see how apache is processing the rewrite rules.  Documentation on log files: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html, see Per-Module logging section.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention that web browsers are aggressively caching redirect 301.

Btw, if you just need simple redirect `domain.tld` to `www.domain.tld` there is special option "Preferred domain" in hosting settings:

[image: plesk-301-redirect-htaccess]

Comment: Any chance you could expand on this a little? How would this make a .htaccess rule still still execute after its been deleted?

Comment: This setting applied in web server config files (nginx/apache) and does not touching .htaccess.

Comment: I don't understand how this applies to the question then?

Comment: From fragment of you .htaccess I get that you need simple redirect domain.tld to www.domain.tld.